# xsl template to get the value-of a child node at specific position in xml

Tags: xml, xslt

First file XML1.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <akn>  
    <meta>
        <identification source="#blah">
            <FRBRWork>
                <FRBRdate date="2011-11-29" name="Generation"/>
            </FRBRWork>
            <FRBRExpression> 123 </FRBRExpression>                      
        </identification>
    </meta>
    <preface> 345</preface>
    <content> 456</content>
 </akn>
```

Second XML file 'XML2.xml'

```
<response>
    <objects type="list">
        <object>
            <name>Anders</name>
            <number> 98 </number>
            <address>SCS</address>
        </object>
        <object>
            <name>Anders</name>
            <number> 98 </number>
            <address>PQR</address>
        </object>
        <object>
            <name>peter</name>
            <number> 58 </number>
            <address>ACS</address>
        </object>
    </objects>
</response>
```

My xls file is as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:akn="http://docs.oasis-open.org/"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd" version="2.0">

    <!--creating shortcut to get acess cListenerOutput.xml file-->
    <xsl:variable name="XML2Output"
        select="document('/src/main/resources/XML2.xml')/objects"/>

        <!-- For stripping the whitespaces in the output xml file -->
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <!-- For defining the output of the transformation -->
        <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="ISO-8859-1"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//akn:meta"/>
            <header>
                <docProponent>
                    <xsl:call-template name="cListener1"/> 
                </docProponent>
            </header>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name = "cListener1">
            <xsl:for-each select="$XML2Output//object">
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="address"/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>   
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

While, the xsl file performs the first operation correctly (extracting the  node), it does not extract the  value from the first instance of the object in the second file.

I also tried to add

```
<xsl:template name = "cListener1" match = "$cListenerOutput/object">
```

but this throws an error

```
Error in expression $cListenerOutput/object: Unexpected token in pattern, found $
```

Can someone point me to the correct approach to use the xml:variable within a template?

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply the **full** xpath in the document variable declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="XML2Output"
        select="document('/src/main/resources/XML2.xml')/response/objects"/>
```

With that single change, the output XML is (hopefully) as you expect:

```
<header xmlns:akn="http://docs.oasis-open.org/">
   <docProponent>SCS</docProponent>
</header>
```